# using a variable to loop and get images in PHP HTML

Tags: php, html, sql

I can't find what is wrong with my code.

I wanted to use $i to get images while in a loop. But it doesn't work. What's wrong?

```
while($i<=64)
{
    $sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE foodId = '".$i."';") or die("Query failed with error: ".pg_last_error($conn));
    $row = pg_fetch_array($sql);
    $j = $i%2;

    if($j==1)
    {
        echo "<label class='checkbox1'> <input type='checkbox' name='foods' value='".$row['foodname']."'>".$row['foodname']."</label><img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'><br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<label class='checkbox2'><input type='checkbox' name='foods' value='".$row['foodname']."'>".$row['foodname']." <label><img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'><br/>";   
    }

    $i++;
}
```

the img tag  is not functioning properly.

Comment: did u initialize $i ?

Comment: How are you setting $i?

Comment: yes $i is initialized to 1

Comment: Are `/images/1.jpg`, `/images/2.jpg` etc. valid relative urls of your site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's either the fact that you've not set i to anything:
    $i = 0;

or the fact you've got ' ' around a number which doesn't work.

Remove the ' ' and set $i to 0.

Should work then.

Edit: You only use ' ' when you're dealing with a string.

If you're images are not showing, run your PHP file in a browser and right click the page and select 'View Source' navigate to where the code is and check what is being called. Your code might not be locating to the right area.

Answer (score 0):

```
$i = 0; // Set $i;
while($i<=64)
{
    $sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE foodId = $i;") or die("Query failed with error: ".pg_last_error($conn));
    $row = pg_fetch_array($sql);
    $j = $i%2;

    if($j==1)
    {
        echo "<label class='checkbox1'> <input type='checkbox' name='foods' value='".$row['foodname']."'>".$row['foodname']."</label><img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'><br/>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "<label class='checkbox2'><input type='checkbox' name='foods' value='".$row['foodname']."'>".$row['foodname']." <label><img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'><br/>";   
    }

    $i++;
}
```

Comment: the query is functioning properly, but the img tag <img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'> is not showing any images.

Answer (score 0):

Minor rewrite of your loop as some noticed that `$i` might not have been initialized properly. I noticed that you missed to close the second label. Although "But it doesn't work." is quite general. Do you get any output at all? Are the image paths wrong? Do the images actually exist?

```
for($i = 0; $i <= 64; $i++)
{
    $sql = pg_query("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE foodId = '".$i."';") or die("Query failed with error: ".pg_last_error($conn));
    $row = pg_fetch_array($sql);

    $class = ($i%2 == 1) ? "checkbox1" : "checkbox2";

    echo "<label class='".$class."'> <input type='checkbox' name='foods' value='".$row['foodname']."'>".$row['foodname']."</label><img src='/images/".$i.".jpg'><br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$result = pg_query("SELECT * FROM foods WHERE foodId < 65;") or die("Query failed with error: ".pg_last_error($conn));
$rows = pg_fetch_all($result);
foreach ( $rows as $row ) {
    $j = ( $row['foodId'] & 1 ? 1 : 2 );

    echo "<label class=\"checkbox{$j}\"> <input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"foods\" value=\"{$row['foodname']}\">{$row['foodname']}</label><img src=\"/images/{$row['foodId']}.jpg\"><br/>";
}
```

Ok, that's a fairly major rewrite - but 65 queries - really ?!  One will do for this :)

$j is being set by checking $row['foodId'] & 1

The \" in echo are just escaping the " marks so we can use "{$php_variable}" - which is nicer imho that all the . concatenation operators.

Your original code had a nasty mix of ' and " - possibly some in the wrong places - maybe why img was failing.

As a couple of people have said - check the generated html source and prove those images really exist - src="/images/1.jpg" is an absolute path - so if you're running this code on localhost/my_test_folder it will fail if images aren't in localhost/images.

Maybe try a relative path - src="images/1.jpg" - no leading /